# How to setup Django/Apache for a designer's dev environment

Tags: django, apache

I've been developing in my own django environment for a while now using the `manage.py runserver` with no problems, but now that we've got a designer and a front-end developer needing to work on the project, I find myself at a loss as to what is the Best Practise for their environments.

I could ask them to setup their own python environment, but that's asking an awful lot since they're not Python people and they're running Windows (my dev and the production environment are both Linux).

So instead, I've set them up on a remote server, the disk of which they can mount locally.  However in this setup, I'm actually using different instances of `manage.py runserver ip:port` running in a `screen` instance.  It doesn't handle things like constant reloads very well (common for our designer) and it hangs from time to time due to the single-threaded nature of the dev server.  I'd like to know how to set this up with Apache.

The problem with this of course is the `staticfiles`.  Every time either of the aforementioned parties want to add or change a static file, they'd have to run `manage.py collectstatic` which just isn't practical.  I just don't know any other way to do it though.  All of the documentation I've found for using Apache is for a production environment, so... that's why I'm here.

Comment: if the designer is only changing static files and templates, why is django reloading?

Comment: Good question.  It happens whenever she does an `svn up`, but that would only be one reload.  Honestly, I don't know why the `runserver` hangs, only that I have to restart it every few days because it stops responding.

Comment: You can try django-devserver. It works just like runserver (actually replaces runserver) but it runs in multiple threads unlike the default runserver. Might at least be more stable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this one was *a lot* simpler than I thought it would be and I apologise for confusing those who responded.  Basically all I wanted was a way to host our designer's dev environment in something more stable than `./manage.py runserver ip:port` in a `screen` session.  I figured that there had to be a way to set something like this up for Apache but had no idea what it was.

Here's what I got to work:

In your `settings.py` set your `STATIC_URL` and `MEDIA_URL` variables to *relative URLs*.  In my case I used `/static/` and `/media/`.

```
MEDIA_ROOT = PROJECT_ROOT + "/htdocs/media/"
MEDIA_URL = "/media/"
SERVE_STATIC = True
STATIC_ROOT = PROJECT_ROOT + "/htdocs/public/"
STATIC_URL = "/static/"
```

Configure Apache as you would if you didn't have any static files at all.  In other words, ignore the recommendations of the docs to use `SetHandler None` in a `<Locaiton>` block.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    WSGIScriptReloading On
    WSGIDaemonProcess someprocessname
    WSGIProcessGroup somegroupname
    WSGIApplicationGroup somegroupname
    WSGIPassAuthorization On

    WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/config.wsgi

    ServerName somewhere.awesome.ca

    <Location "/">
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from all
    </Location>

    ErrorLog  /var/log/apache2/somewhere.awesome.ca.err
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/somewhere.awesome.ca.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

- Lastly, you just have to follow the Django howto for serving `staticfiles` through Python at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/howto/static-files/#serving-other-directories

I hope this helps to point someone in the right direction in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Source control? Have them check in changes and then set up a post commit hook to collectstatic and restart the server. With nice windows GUIs I've never had a designer who couldn't grasp the basic concepts. If you're using a dcvs you can always have them in their own fork so you have to merge into the main repos to prevent them from breaking other things by mistake.

Comment: They're both very comfortable with subversion commands (cli and gui), but I don't want to force them to commit just to change the colour in CSS.  It'd be slow, and would fill the logs with superfulous changes.  I was hoping to find an Apache config that could reproduce that merging effect the `runserver` does.

Comment: Have you thought about usin mod_wsgi or fast_cgi? If you touch the script file they're running it'll reload the server